# Filling struct's array crashes with Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

> Just for the record: I spent a while already checking similar
>   questions and trying their proposed answers without success

I am facing a "Segmentation fault" error in runtime with the following C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ROW_NUM     8
#define COL_NUM     7

typedef struct {
    int matrix[ROW_NUM][COL_NUM];
} screen_type;

typedef struct {
    screen_type *p_screen;
} snake_type;

void fillSnake(snake_type *p_snake);

int main(void) {
    snake_type snake;
    fillSnake(&snake);
    return 0;
}

void fillSnake(snake_type *p_snake) {
    fillWithPointer((screen_type*)p_snake->p_screen);
}

void fillWithPointer(screen_type *p_screen) { //segmentation fault in this method
    for (int col = 0; col < COL_NUM; col++) {
        for (int row = 0; row < ROW_NUM; row++) {
            p_screen->matrix[row][col] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is while filling the array with the method `fillWithPointer`.
Any hints will be more than welcome.

Comment: Has the `p_screen` member (of the `p_snake` passed to `fillSnake`) been allocated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `main` function, `snake` is never initialized, and so its `p_snake` member is left as a pointer to some arbitrary location in memory.  You then attempt to write to this memory within `fillWithPointer`, which you are not allowed to do, hence the segmentation fault.

To correct this error, allocate some memory for the `snake`, either on the stack or the heap. One way to accomplish this would be the following:

```
int main(void) {
    screen_type screen = {{{0}}};
    snake_type snake = {&screen};
    fillSnake(&snake);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that since the screen is already zero-initialized, your `fillWithPointer` functions becomes superfluous.

Comment: Thanks!!! Could you help me do that?? I am quite new to these C programs...

Answer (score 1):

As my understanding according to your code you have to do malloc struct snake_type before passing into method in main method.
snake_type* snake = (snake_type*)malloc(sizeof(snake_type));

Fillsnake(snake);

Comment: Could you please show me how in code? Thank you very much!!

Comment: Note that this code snippet exhibits a [poor practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) in C and should not be copied verbatim.

Comment: Thank you veeery much, even when I've selected @Brian answer,  your response also has helped me to understand what was the problem